# AlertManager behaviour with FIRING alerts

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am using textfile collector to export to the statistics.prom file, updated every minute by the update-statistics.sh script. Here's an example of the .prom file.

```
item_has_stock{id="item.aaa", store="x"} 1
item_has_stock{id="item.aaa", store="y"} 1
item_has_stock{id="item.bbb", store="z"} 1
item_has_stock{id="item.ccc", store="k"} 1
```

Everytime update-statistics.sh runs the stock value may change from "1" to "0", and vice versa. Now, say the .prom file was updated to:

```
item_has_stock{id="item.aaa", store="x"} 1
item_has_stock{id="item.aaa", store="y"} 0
item_has_stock{id="item.bbb", store="z"} 0
item_has_stock{id="item.ccc", store="k"} 0
```

Alertmanager, sends the following alert:

```
[FIRING:3] Item Stock
Item item.aaa at store y
Item item.bbb at store z
Item item.ccc at store k
```

On the next run of update-statistics.sh the value of item_has_stock{id="aaa", store="y"} changes from "0" to "1" as shown below.

```
item_has_stock{id="item.aaa", store="x"} 1
item_has_stock{id="item.aaa", store="y"} 1
item_has_stock{id="item.bbb", store="z"} 0
item_has_stock{id="item.ccc", store="k"} 0
```

Now, the alert sent by alertmanager looks like this:

```
[FIRING:2] Item Stock
Item item.aaa at store y
Item item.bbb at store z
Item item.ccc at store k
```

The FIRING count decremented correctly, but the line "Item item.aaa at store y" should not be displayed anymore... Here's the alertmanager configuration:

```
route:
  receiver: 'default'

  routes:
  - receiver: 'item-stock'
    group_by: ['item_has_stock']
    group_wait: 45s
    group_interval: 1m
    repeat_interval: 2m
    match_re:
      id: .*item.*

receivers:
  - name: 'default'
    slack_configs:
    - send_resolved: true
      api_url: '...'
      channel: '#channel'
      username: 'alertmanager'

  - name: 'item-stock'
    slack_configs:
    - send_resolved: true
      api_url: '...'
      channel: '#channel'
      username: 'alertmanager'
      title: '[{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] Item Stock'
      text: "{{ range .Alerts }}\nItem {{ .Labels.id }} at store {{ .Labels.store }}{{ end }}"
```

The next FIRING alerts, triggered every 3 minutes (group_interval + repeat_interval), look the same as the above example. Only after 15 min (i.e. after 5 alerts), the line "Item item.aaa at store y" finally disapears. Additionaly, I would expect a RESOLVED alert for this line...

PS: The item-stock.rule file contains the expression "expr: item_has_stock == 0" to trigger the alert when the value changes from "1" to "0".

Answer (score 3):

You set `send_resolved: true`, so your notifications contain a mix of firing and resolved alerts as shown by the `[FIRING:2]` with three alerts in the body.

You should remove the `send_resolved: true`.

Comment: thanks. It solves one part. However, I'd like to see a RESOLVED alert for "Item item.aaa at store y". How can I do that?

Comment: You need to work off the resolved Status that alert has in your templating.

Comment: It seems to work only after all the previous "0" turn to "1". I can't find a way to send a single RESOLVED alert for that single item_has_stock.

Comment: You'd need to add `id` and `store` to your group_by for that, which is not advisable as it could get spammy.

Comment: Interestingly, what does the "2" in `[FIRING:2]` mean?